# Is there a way in Selenium to overcome Safari browser's same origin policy in click on a button within iFrame?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cross-domain, mobile-safari

I'm trying to click on a Submit button within an iFrame. Trying to switch with iFrame id gives "Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame" error.

```html
<iframe id="challengeFrame" name="challengeFrame" width="250" height="400">
<html>
<body>
<form id="capture" class="challenge-form" action="capture" method="POST">
  <div class="column">
    <ul class="options">
           <li>
                ....
           </li> 
        
           <li>
                ...
           </li> 
        
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
        <input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit">
  </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
</iframe>
```

In the above iFrame I need to click on the submit button. Please suggest any method with example to achieve this in Selenium Java/JS framework.

Comment: It's so annoying that Safari has this same origin policy mess, I've been working on finding a solution for a while now, but... well.. I guess the point of this policy is that you should not be able to bypass it.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to include in your chrome options this argument:

```
options.add_argument("--disable-web-security")
```

This should disable the CORS check.

Comment: Hi, I'm using Safari browser on iOS devices for testing which has this same origin policy issue.